# Add features to main SDE Table with geotools

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, geotools

Sorry for my english, I hope you can understand ;)
I'am using geotools 8.4 version. I try to copy all features from SDE Table(TEST.DBO.MM_SOURCE) to another SDE Table(TEST.DBO.MM_TEST). All features are copied correctly, but they are not stored in main table (TEST.DBO.MM_TEST). When I open ArcMap, edit some feature in TEST.DBO.MM_TEST and save, all features are back in main table. Both SDE tables are registered as versioned and moving edits to base. What I must do to store all features in main table?

Here is my java code:

```
String server = "localhost";
String port = "5151";
String database = "Test";
String user = "sa";
String password = "sa";
String version = "dbo.Default";

connector = new SDEConnector();
connector.setConnectionParameters(server, port, database, user, password, version);
connector.connect();

SimpleFeatureStore dataStore =
        (SimpleFeatureStore) connector.getDataStore().getFeatureSource("TEST.DBO.MM_TEST");

SimpleFeatureCollection fc1 = connector.getFeatureCollection("TEST.DBO.MM_SOURCE")
SimpleFeatureCollection fc2 = dataStore.getFeatures();

SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = fc1.features();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
    Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(fc2.getSchema());
    builder.set("Shape", geometry);
    builder.set("P1", feature.getAttribute("P1"));
    builder.set("P2", feature.getAttribute("P2"));
    builder.set("Source_OID", 829023);
    builder.set("Marker", 10);

    SimpleFeature sf = builder.buildFeature(null);
    // SimpleFeature sf = builder.buildFeature(builder.createDefaultFeatureId());

    List<SimpleFeature> list = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();
    list.add(sf);

    dataStore.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(list));
}
iterator.close();
time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
System.out.println(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit the changes to the datastore. You'll need some code like:

```
 if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try {
            featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception problem) {
            problem.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
        System.exit(0); // success!
    } else {
        System.out.println(typeName + " does not support read/write access");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

See [this tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html#write-the-feature-data-to-the-shapefile) for more details.